# How to Create My theme in Magento2 Stable version

Tags: magento2

How to Create My theme in Magento2 Stable version
Any one have idea ?

Answer (score 1):

See the official documentation: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-general.html

Comment: I think it's old documentation.

Comment: @hweb87 why do you think it is old? Old as in date wise? or Magento1 wise?

Comment: It should be up to date. If you know of a specific issue, plesae let us know.